# Reversing the velocity doesn't work after being built

Tags: unity, c#, physics

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class AlienMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float screenBorder = 30;

    public float moveSpeed = 1.0f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float maxVariability = 4.0f;
    public float minVariability = -4.0f;

    private Camera camera1;

    private void Start()
    {
        camera1 = Camera.main;

        // Generate a random variability within the specified range
        float variability = Random.Range(minVariability, maxVariability);

        // Set the velocity based on variability
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(variability, 0) * moveSpeed;
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        reverseVelocity();
    }

    /*
     * Checks if the Alien is near the border
     * Changes the direction to the opposite way if the Alien hits the border
     */
    private void reverseVelocity()
    {
        Vector2 screenPosition = camera1.WorldToScreenPoint(rb.position);
        if ((screenPosition.x < screenBorder) || (screenPosition.x > camera1.pixelWidth - screenBorder))
        {
            //Reverses the direction
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-rb.velocity.x, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Boundaries : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera MainCamera;
    public Vector2 screenBounds { get; private set; }
    private float objectWidth;
    private float objectHeight;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        MainCamera = FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
        screenBounds = MainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, MainCamera.transform.position.z));
        objectWidth =  transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.extents.x; //extents = size of width / 2
        objectHeight = transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.extents.y; //extents = size of height / 2
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 viewPos = transform.position;
        viewPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(viewPos.x, screenBounds.x * -1 + objectWidth, screenBounds.x - objectWidth);
        viewPos.y = Mathf.Clamp(viewPos.y, screenBounds.y * -1 + objectHeight, screenBounds.y - objectHeight);
        transform.position = viewPos;
    }
}
```

In the Unity editor, the code works, allowing the alien to reverse their velocity when it touches the border. However, the alien is stuck at the border after building the game.

[Videos](https://imgur.com/a/1XbVY7y)